# Error 1062: duplicate entry in non-primary field

Tags: mysql

I have recently started to work with MySQL for my study job and now face following problem:

My predecessor created a textmining table of the following structure:

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| TokenId    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| Value      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Frequency  | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| PMID       | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

In the context of restructuring, I added the following column:

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| NewTokenId | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

If I now run the query:

```
insert into TitleToken(NewTokenId) select t.TokenId from Token as t, TitleToken as tt where t.Value = tt.Value
```

or even the query:

```
insert into TitleToken(NewTokenId) values(1);
```

I get following output:

> ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

As I said, I am relatively new to (hands-on) *SQL and it feels like a stupid mistake, but since the column NewTokenId is no primary key, not unique and even Null is YES, I thought I'd be able to insert basically anything I want.

Any hint would be appreciated... thanks in advance :)

Comment: Problem lies with `TokenId`. Is should be auto increment

Comment: Please read the error message carefully. It doesn't complaint about `NewTokenId`, it complaints about the primary key (i.e. `TokenId`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you have a default value for the primary key "TokenID", if you do not insert a value for the key in your insert statement the system will automatically insert 0. However, if there is another tuple with the same value for this attribute (which is probable because the default is 0) you will get that error.

Comment: OK, the functionality I wanted was actually UPDATE, not INSERT. Thanks for the answer, it put me in the right direction really quick :)

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to perform an insert into a table without providing a unique value for `TokenId`. By default, according to the table description, `TokenId` defaults to `0`, you cannot have multiple identical values in that column.